# How can I get an URL's host without schema and ending in php?

Tags: php, arrays, url, explode

I want to explode urls to get the host.

```
$link = str_replace("www.", "", $_POST['link']);
$part1 = explode("//", $link);
$part2 = explode(".", $part1[1]);
$host = $part2[0];
```

So if the `$_POST['link']` is e.g.

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udm5jUA-2bs
```

I want to get just `youtube`.
In this first way I get `explode()` expects parameter 2 to be string, array given" error message.

With this method:

```
$host = var_dump(parse_url($_POST['link'], PHP_URL_HOST));
```

I get `www.youtube.com` but I want only `youtube`.

Comment: If your link is `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udm5jUA-2bs`, doesn't the first method already work? https://3v4l.org/Moeht

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Extract the url domain using [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function with mode `PHP_URL_HOST`.
- We will use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to break it into parts using `.` as delimiter.
- Now, the URL can be of two types, either `youtube.com`, or `www.youtube.com`, or `%.youtube.com`
- We count the parts, and if they are two, we use the first value, else the second value.

DEMO:  https://3v4l.org/KlErW

```
$url_host_parts = explode('.', parse_url($_POST['link'], PHP_URL_HOST));
$host = (count($url_host_parts) == 2) ? $url_host_parts[0] : $url_host_parts[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

what about this without any `regex`? You can use `parse_url()` and `explode()` to get what you want i.e **youtube**

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udm5jUA-2bs';
$parse = parse_url($url);
//print_r($parse);
echo explode('.',$parse['host'])[1];
?>
```

**Output:**

```
 youtube
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/kG1nD

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex in `preg_match()` to do this work.

```
$url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udm5jUA-2bs";
preg_match("/(\w+)(?=\.\w{2,}(\/|\?|$))/", $url, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; // youtube
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/jh6rB)